# Get content from specific tag with its class name from html string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a little problem.
With GET method I am getting data as an HTML String.
And now, I want to display only data from:

CONTENT

How I can filter only this tag and class from the html string that is returned with GET method?

Thank you.

Comment: can you post a bit of your code ?

Comment: `code` <div class="wiki-holder prepend-top-default append-bottom-default">CONTENT</div>

Comment: I need to get this div tag with its class from the html string.

Comment: @M.Kolev You need to add what you tried yourself.

Comment: I tried with: creating my own div element with id "content" where I wanted to store filtered string like this: var x = document.getElementById("DIV").classList.contains("wiki-holder prepend-top-default append-bottom-default");    and then document.getElementById("content").innerHtml = x;  But without success.

Comment: Also, I tried with this: var list = document.getElementsByClassName("wiki-holder prepend-top-default append-bottom-default"); and then document.getElementById("content").innerHtml =  list; and still nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to create a DOM element and set the `innerHTML` property to the HTML string.

```js
let res = '<div class="wiki-holder prepend-top-default append-bottom-default">CONTENT</div>';//In your case this will contain the whole HTML string

let div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = res;
let selected = div.getElementsByClassName('wiki-holder prepend-top-default append-bottom-default');

document.write(selected[0].innerHTML);//The first element of this className
```

Comment: But the tag with class="wiki-holder prepend-top-default append-bottom-default" is in the string named "res".

Comment: Could you clarify what do you want to do. I think I misread your question.

Comment: Well, I have HTML string named "res" that contain whole data returned from GET method. When I wrote: document.write(res), the browser displaying data properly. But, I want to display only the content that is in "<div>" with class="wiki-holder prepend-top-default append-bottom-default". I need to display only content that is in this tag.

Comment: @M.Kolev please consider marking as answered once you get your answer.

Comment: perfect solution